# Keycloak: Hide IDP for certain client

Tags: keycloak

I have several client applications behind my keycloak server.

Only for some of them the users should be able to login via external idp.
For the rest of the clients the external idp should be hidden on the keycloak login page.

How can I configure the idp to only be available for certain clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I didnt found the actual solution I figured out a workaround.

I can configure a custom theme per client. So I designed a login theme that doesnt display the external idps.
Now some clients show the original theme while others show the custom theme without external idps...